# AngularJS : Enhancing or wrapping promises with pre/post resolve/reject actions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, restangular, angular-promise

**Goal**

I'm trying to create a series of promise 'enhancers' which will add functionality (such as caching, queuing, redirect handling, etc.) around existing promises which are simple http requests.

**Problem**

The issue I'm experiencing with this method of enhancing promises is that if an enhancement adds any functions or publicly accessible properties to the promise (or if I'm wrapping an already-enhanced promise like a restangular request), those are lost when I wrap it in a new promise by returning a new `$q`.

**Question**

What pattern can I use to enhance or wrap promises (like in the two examples below), but without losing any other (non-conflicting) enhancements promises might have?

**Example 1**

Here is an example that will automatically handle 503-Retry-After errors:

```
function _enhancePromiseWithAutoRetry(promise) {
  var enhancedPromise = $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    var newReject = get503Handler(this, resolve, reject);
    promise.then(resolve, newReject);
  });

  // 503 handling isn't enabled until the user calls this function.
  enhancedPromise.withAutoRetry = function(onRetry, timeout) {
    var newPromise = angular.copy(this);
    newPromise._503handled = true;
    newPromise._503onRetry = onRetry;
    newPromise._503timeout = timeout;
    return newPromise;
  };

  return enhancedPromise;
}
```

The idea is that if I return a promise enhanced with the above function, the user can go:

```
someRequest.withAutoRetry().then(onSuccess, onError);
```

Or to be more clear (with chaining):

```
someRequest.then(onSuccess, onAnyError)
           .withAutoRetry().then(onSuccess, onNon503Error);
```

Here, the first call to `then(...)` might error out right away if the server is busy, but the calls after `.withAutoRetry()` will poll the server with repeated requests until the response is successful, or a non `RetryAfter` error is returned.

**Example 2**

Here is an another example which adds custom caching behaviour:

```
function _enhancePromiseWithCache(promise, cacheGet, cachePut) {
  // Wrap the old promise with a new one that will get called first.
  return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
    // Check if the value is cached using the provided function
    var cachedResponse = cacheGet !== undefined ? cacheGet() : undefined;
    if(cachedResponse !== undefined){
      resolve(cachedResponse);
    } else {
      // Evaluate the wrapped promise, cache the result, then return it.
      promise.then(cachePut);
      promise.then(resolve, reject);
    }
  });
}
```

This one allows the library to set up a cache of data which can be used instead of making requests to the server, and can be added to after a request is completed. For example:

```
lib.getNameOrigin = function(args) {
  var restRequest = Restangular.all('people').one(args.id).get('nameOrigin');
  // Cache, since all people with the same name will have the same name origin
  var enhancedPromise = _enhancePromiseWithCache(restRequest,
                          function(){ return nameOrigins[args.name]; },
                          function(val){ nameOrigins[args.name] = val; });
  return enhancedPromise;
}
```

Elsewhere

```
// Will transparently populate the cache
lib.getNameOrigin({id: 123, name:'john'}).then(onSuccess, onError).then(...);
```

And somewhere else entirely

```
// Will transparently retrieve the result from the cache rather than make request
lib.getNameOrigin({id: 928, name:'john'}).then(onSuccess, onError);
```

**Possible Solution**

I've considered copying the original promise, but then overwriting the new one's `then` function with an implementation that references the original promise's `then` (using the [Proxy Pattern](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Proxy_Pattern)), but is this safe? I know there's a lot more to promises than just the `then` function.

Comment: This changes between Angular 1.2 and Angular 1.3, is that relevant for you? Which would you like me to focus on? In either case you have to override the `then`, it is safe as long as your `.then` is Promises/A+ complaint

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I understand your use case `$http(...).cache().then(...` makes sense but `$http(...).then(function(){ return 3}).cache()` doesn't make sense, is 3 cached? Where? To what point? It actually does make sense that those methods only affect the other side. Can you be more specific about what you're adding?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the most recent version of angular is fine. What about the `.catch()` method? Does that have to be overridden too or is it guaranteed to simply call `.then(undefined, reject)`?

Comment: Guaranteed? No, but in practice it does. It is only guaranteed to have the same effect. Although - I think what I wrote about chaining being problematic to begin with is significant. What does caching or queueing mean after it was chained?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum the second use case is for a library to `return enhancePromiseWithCache($http(...), cache.makeGetterFor(args), cache.makePutterFor(args))`. The user would return the consume the promise normally: `someRequest.then(onSuccess, onFailure).then(somethingElse);`, only the `$http` request/response gets intercepted.

Comment: What about `requestAndCache._p = null; function getAndCache(){ return p || (p = $http.apply(this, arguments)) }` - why would you need a wrapper over promises themselves for this?

Comment: That does not require resolving the promise before the user has called then. The promise is cached rather than the response. This is also free of race conditions in case the user makes multiple requests before the first one resolved.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I've added sample usages to my two above examples to demonstrate the intended usage and that chaining before or after using promise enhancements is not a problem. They also demonstrate why it isn't sufficient to simply cache the promise itself.

Comment: If there's any further questions as to why I want to *enhance* a promise and not just add my own `then()` call in before the user, please see the following article: http://gon.to/2013/05/02/enhancing-angular-promises-returning-new-promise-of-field-or-method-called-from-original-promises-result/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59824/discussion-between-benjamin-gruenbaum-and-alain).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not to enhance the promises themselves, but the factories that create them.

Use functional programming and/or aspect-orientated programming approaches to decorate the original function. This will not only be less errorprone, but more concise, composable and reusable.

```
function decorate(makeThenable) {
    return function(...args) {
        … // before creating the thenable
        return makeThenable(...args).then(function(value) {
            … // handle fulfillment
            return …; // the resulting value
        }, function(error) {
            … // handle rejection
            return …; // (or throw)
        });
    };
}
var decorated = decorate(myThenablemaker);
decorated(…).then(whenFulfilled, whenRejected);
```

**Example 1:**

```
function withAutoRetry(request, timeout) {
    return function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return request.apply(null, args).catch(function handle(e) {
            if (e instanceof Http503Error) // or whatever
                return request.apply(null, args).catch(handle);
            else
                throw e;
        });
    };
}
```

```
withAutoRetry(someRequest)().then(onSuccess, onError);

withAutoRetry(function() {
    return someRequest().then(onSuccess, onAnyError);
})().then(onSuccess, onNon503Error);
```

**Example 2:**

```
function withCache(request, hash) {
    var cache = {};
    if (!hash) hash = String;
    return function() {
        var key = hash.apply(this, arguments);
        if (key in cache)
            return cache[key];
        else
            return cache[key] = request.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

```
lib.getNameOrigin = withCache(function(args) {
    return Restangular.all('people').one(args.id).get('nameOrigin');
}, function(args) {
    return args.name;
});
```

Comment: I'm finding it hard to separate your implementation of specific features (caching / 503 handling) from your general approach here. From what I can guess, your approach mainly has to do with the use of `apply`. Could you perhaps elaborate or add an example that involves wrapping any arbitrary thennable with arbitrary actions that takes place: 1. before `resolve`, 2. after `resolve`, 3. before `reject`, 4. after `reject`?

Comment: From your **Example 2**, it looks like calling `lib.getNameOrigin({id: 123, name:'john'}).then(onSuccess, onError)` will result in an `TypeError: .then is not a function` error if `'john'` is in `cache`, because in that case it returns the cached result object directly instead of a thennable. Am I misunderstanding your implementation?

Comment: +1, this is similar to what we ended up doing after all the debate about `using` in Bluebird. Decorating a whole chain is definitely a way to do this. This is still not how I'd cache but definitely a better approach than overriding `.then`.

Comment: @Alain: The cache contains the promises, not the values. Which has the additional benefit that a second call during a ongoing request returns the same promise as the first call, instead of starting a second request.

Comment: @Alain: I've tried to make add a general example now. I wasn't sure what you meant by "before"/"after" resolution of which thenable - you usually don't know when it's "before". Notice that the `handleX` arbitrary functions are not "actions", but normal `then` handlers that need to `return` a value for chaining.

Comment: The main limitation with this method is it only allows you to add your own `resolve` or `reject` actions giving the promise to the user. The whole point of the `withAutoRetry` enhancement is that it adds a new method to the promise `withAutoRetry()` which gives the user the *option* of enabling that feature on a promise that's already been set up (and possibly already resolved), rather than forcing them to construct two different promises and make two separate requests if they want to to resolve with and without the auto-retry behavior.

Comment: For example, I currently go `var request = server.getResults(args)...; request.then(onSuccess, function(){ if( confirm('Server Busy. Do you wish to continue polling for this request?') ) request.withAutoRetryAfter().then(onSuccess, onError); });` This is possible with my solution so far, but not with yours as far as I can tell.

Comment: Also, to address your earlier comment, caching promises is definitely not desirable in this case, because the server might reply with "503 Retry-After 5000" for the first request, and return a 200 on a subsequent request. If the promises are cached, once the first promise resolves with the 503 error, all future requests will just return that same error instead of making a fresh request like I want. That's part of the reason why I'm managing caching myself in this example, not using generic request caching. That's why it's important that this enhancement's code take place before `resolve`.

Comment: About your new example: if I have a thennable request (such as what is returned by restangular), and my library returns `return decorate(Restangular.all('asdf').one(...).withHttpConfig()...);` Then request is no longer thennable, correct? I can no longer call `var request = getRequest(id); ...; request.then(...)`, I have to call `request()` (which resolves the promise prematurely) followed by `.then(...)` so `request().then(...)`. If my library is supposed to return promises that are A+ compliant, then it would be incorrect to force the user to use that syntax.

Comment: No. This approach does not aim to add methods to promises (which is subclassing `Promise`, and is complicated to propagate) - it "adds" methods (OK, they're static functions actually) to the functions that return the promises. This is much more powerful as it allows you to also intercept the `args` - in fact with your method that takes a promise it's impossible to program an autoretry feature: you don't know what the try was, and can't *invoke* it again.

Comment: Caching of promises (and handing out errors to multiple subscribers) vs. caching of results (and possibly firing multiple parallel requests) is a trade-off. You could easily adapt the solution to only cache the first fulfilled promise by adding an `onFulfilled` handler that sets the cache. Or, given your example, you should do `withCache(withAutoRetry(request))` instead of `withAutoRetry(withCache(request))` :-)

Comment: About your last comment: you don't `decorate` the thenable, but the function that *makes* the thenable. In this case, `library.method = decorate(function(){ return Restangular.all('asdf').one(...).withHttpConfig()...; })`. You always call `getRequest` to make a `request` thenable, regardless whether `getRequest` was decorated before calling it or not. The thenable is not a function of course.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59826/discussion-between-alain-and-bergi).

Comment: Well I'm definitely going to upvote you because this has been very helpful suggestion and discussion, but I'll still have to struggle with my goals and trying to fit them into the pattern of modifying promise factories rather than promises themselves. I'll come back when I've hashed out a solution.

Comment: I took your advice and settled on this pattern: http://plnkr.co/edit/BH5tdy1x8xSg2o5gIJ3e?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I proposed in my **Possible Solution** section, so that it can be discussed in detail.

I've considered copying the original promise, but then overwriting the new one's `then` function with an implementation that resolves the original promise, but is this safe?

**New Example**

```
function _enhancePromiseWithQueuing(promise, id) {
  // Copy the old promise and overwrite its then method.
  var enhancedPromise = angular.copy(promise);
  enhancedPromise.then = function(resolve, reject) {
    // Resolves the original promise once the existing `id` queue is clear.
    queue.enqueueRequest(id, function() { promise.then(resolve, reject); });
    return this;
  };
  return enhancedPromise;
}
```

**Example 1** (from above)

```
function _enhancePromiseWithAutoRetry(promise) {    
  // Copy the old promise and enhance it with the withAutoRetry method.
  var enhancedPromise = angular.copy(promise);
  // Add a function that enables 503 Retry-After handling when called.
  enhancedPromise.withAutoRetry = function(onRetry, timeout) {
    // Copy the old promise and overwrite its then method.
    var promiseWith503Handling = angular.copy(this);
    promiseWith503Handling.then = function(resolve, reject) {
      // Call the original promise then method with a modified reject handler.
      return this.then(resolve, get503Handler(this, resolve, reject,
                                              onRetry, timeout, new Date()));
    };
    return promiseWith503Handling;
  };    
  return enhancedPromise;
}
```

**Example 2** (from above)

```
function _enhancePromiseWithCache(promise, cacheGet, cachePut) {
  var enhancedPromise = angular.copy(promise);
  enhancedPromise.then = function(resolve, reject) {
    // Check if the value is cached using the provided function
    var cachedResponse = cacheGet !== undefined ? cacheGet() : undefined;
    if(cachedResponse !== undefined){
      return resolve(cachedResponse);
    } else {
      // Resolve the original promise, cache the result, then return it.
      promise.then(cachePut);
      return promise.then(resolve, reject);
    }
  };
  return enhancedPromise;
}
```

Comment: Overwriting `then` *can* be safe, but requires a lot of attention (it's errorprone), and probably destroys most of the optimisations that the promise library put there; as well as some other library-dependent features.

Comment: @Bergi I thought it would be dangerous, but I couldn't find any examples of where it might cause problems. Providing no errors are made, what features or optimizations might it destroy?

Comment: An error I can spot in your implementations is that the new `then` doesn't return anything. Features like progress messaging or cancellation (whatever the promise library supports) would need to be integrated in the solution, and make it very implementation-dependent (in contrast to my approach, which does not require modification when the promise lib is swapped). The optimisations are implementation-dependent as well, many libraries use smaller primitives than the `then` method of the involved promises to implement their `then` method.

Comment: You're right, I missed adding in return statements after switching over from the `$q` constructor.